# How to move data between Azure SQL database instances

Tags: sql, azure

I have a simple Azure website and Azure SQL database. I have now created a new (empty) Azure SQL database and I want to copy the contents of the old database into the new one. The data is only a few kB in size but it would be a pain to do it manually. What is a quick and easy way to do this, using simple tools like Visual Studio and Azure portal?

So just to be clear I want to copy all tables and rows to the new DB.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out you can do this using the Azure portal.

On the original database, choose Export. You need a storage account in the same region as the database for this.

After exporting the database to a .bapac file, choose New / SQL Database / Import and point it to the bapac file. If this is in a different data centre, it will incur data bandwidth charges.

Very simple and this worked great; just a little difficult to find at first.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to such operation, I use Sql Server Data Tools. It`s a plugin for Visual Studio that allow you to copy data, schema and migrate from one version to another.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/

Comment: OK, but how do you use it to do what I asked?

Comment: @TobySharp If you install SSDT you'll see. It will add a plugin in your VS called "Data". In there you can choose "Compare Scheme" "Compare data", set the data sources (your old db, your new, and compare both). It will create the tables, views, procs, or whatever you have and export data if you want.

Comment: OK, thanks. In the end I did it within the Azure management portal. Also, it looks like SSDT is now part of VS2013.